# How to refer each UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I add 10 buttons to UIScrollView

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

     UIButton *btn =  ....  

     [ScrollView addSubview:btn];

}
```

How can i refer to each button ?

Comment: You don't need that `int` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
btn.tag = i;
```

and later,

```
[scrollView viewWithTag: 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Either set the tag on each view, and find them using viewWithTag, or save references to each in an NSMutableArray or other data structure.